# Joomla Error Messages for Specific User Group

Tags: joomla, usergroups

I'm trying to set up customer error messages for different user groups in Joomla 3.6. We have locked content on the front-end of our site, currently there is a generic message that tells the user to login to see it, however we recently adjusted our user groups to create multiple levels of access so even after logging in there may still be content the user can't see. In those instances I need to be able to show a message specific to that user group rather than a generic "please login".

I have used Language Overrides for custom messages before but there's no option I've found to have it show to specific groups. I don't know a lot about code, and Google revealed no existing answers for this.

Answer (score 0):

This might be something to get you going:

```
$groups = JUserHelper::getUserGroups((int) $user->user_id); 

if(in_array(8, $groups))
{ 

    $level = 'admin';

} elseif (in_array(4, $groups)) {

    $level = 'globalmoderator';

} elseif (in_array(3, $groups)) {

    $level = 'moderator';

} elseif (in_array(2, $groups)) {

    $level = 'user';

} else {

    $level = 'guest';

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Where would I apply this?

Comment: You can use it in your template override file

Answer (score 0):

Without some programming it'll not be easy for you to achieve. But in short, you can create a pretty simple plugin, which will capture certain Joomla events.

For example, Joomla has onUserLogin even, which allows you to do different stuff, when user logs in. Your custom plugin can capture this even, check for some parameters and then add a group specific message to the queue. More over, you can get current message queue, parse or empty it and then add group specific message.

You can do the same for any other Joomla event like onUserLogout, onUserLoginFailure and so on. There're plenty events to choose from.

As for message specific groups, you can add your own generic messages similar to this:

> COM_USERS_ERROR_LOGIN_GUEST
>
> COM_USERS_ERROR_LOGIN_REGISTERED
>
> COM_USERS_ERROR_LOGIN_ADMIN

Then you just take "COM_USERS_ERROR_LOGIN_" string and add a group name (or ID, when language is non-English) to it. That's it.

The task doesn't seem too complex, but you still have to know some coding to create a plugin, which will capture Joomla events. There's no other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use articles for messages and filter it with permissions for user groups.

Comment: At this point this looks to be what I'm going to do. I will change he current message we have that displays to all to be generic, then user user group permissions via modules to prompt specific groups to take certain actions.